# How to use two Y axes in Chart.js v2?

Tags: javascript, browser, graph, chart.js

I am trying to create a line chart with two datasets, each with its own Y scale / axis (one to the left, one to the right of the graph) using Chart.js.

This is my code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqx627kt/)):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'A',
        yAxesGroup: 'A',
        data: [ 100, 96, 84, 76, 69 ]
      },
      {
        label: 'B',
        yAxesGroup: 'B',
        data: [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        name: 'A',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'left',
        scalePositionLeft: true
      },
      {
        name: 'B',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'right',
        scalePositionLeft: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 1
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

However, the second axis is not visible and the second dataset is still scaled exactly as the first (0 to 100 instead of 0 to 1). What do I need to change?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

For ChartJs 2.x only a couple changes need to be made (it looks like you have tried to combine 2.x options with the multi-axes options from my fork?),

- The `yAxes` field needs to be in a `scales` object
- the yAxis is referenced by id not name.
- For the scale steps/size you just need to wrap these options in a `ticks` object.
- No need for`scalePositionLeft` this is covered by `position`

Example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'A',
      yAxisID: 'A',
      data: [100, 96, 84, 76, 69]
    }, {
      label: 'B',
      yAxisID: 'B',
      data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: 'A',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'left',
      }, {
        id: 'B',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'right',
        ticks: {
          max: 1,
          min: 0
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/vjt2r1mL/)

Comment: When I open your fiddle, both axes are there, but the second dataset (`B`) is still not scaled to the right axis (`B`), why not?

Comment: sorry typo on my part should be `yAxisID` not `yAxesID`

Comment: @Quince Hi Quince but how to applied two different type of chart (line and bar) with your code. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Bcktr im sure you can just change the type to a bar. (or are you showing a bar and a line in the same graph?
)  Not near a computer at the moment but I feel that should work.

Comment: Upvoted, I was looking for a way to put 2 line of codes in the yaxes
yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display:false
                    }   
                }]

Was putting the comma in the wrong place xD

Comment: Does anyone know how you can remove the right hand side figures that go up along the y axis? So there's not labels along the first `y axis` AND the second `y axis` that appears on the right?

Comment: Do you know how to set ticks (min/max) automatically by data? It works for left-axis, by default right-axis is 0-1

Comment: Do you know how to add different units of measurements for each of the Y axes?

Comment: Unfortunately, one scale affects the other if more than 2 series are involved. Works fine with 2 lines of diff scales, but add a 3rd one with diff scales, no longer works.

Comment: This is no longer working as of **Chart.js 3.5** and, and is listed as part of the breaking changes for 3.0. See below for an updated answer

Comment: BTW axes have default ids if you don't provide them. You can reference the axes by these in the datasets in that case: `x-axis-0`, `y-axis-0`, `y-axis-1`.

Answer (score 44):

The accepted answer no longer works as of 3.5, and the cause is listed as part of the breaking changes for 3.X (See [3.x Migration Guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html))

The updated code below changes the `scales` property, from `scales: {yScales: [...]}` to `scales: {[id]: {[options]}}` , and also adds `fill: true,` (Was changed at 3.X from defaulting to `true`) and `tension: 0.4` (The example provided before does have smooth curves, and seems like it was an undocumented "breaking" change)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'A',
            yAxisID: 'A',
            data: [100, 96, 84, 76, 69],
            fill: true,
            tension: 0.4
        }, {
            label: 'B',
            yAxisID: 'B',
            data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            fill: true,
            tension: 0.4
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            A: {
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'left',
            },
            B: {
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'right',
                ticks: {
                    max: 1,
                    min: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This helped me out. To others, here's a link to the latest docs on this https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.0/samples/line/multi-axis.html

Comment: Right, because the question is about Chart.js 2 not 3

Comment: But its still the top result for 2 y axes chartjs on google, and having a solution for V3 helps people to not look up a migration guide for a snippet they got from SO

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working in react.

```
// "chart.js": "^2.9.4"
// "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1"


const lineChartData = {
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      },
      {
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [19, 9, 2, 1, 1, 21],
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(122, 99, 255)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(102, 99, 255, 0.2)',
      }
    ],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          type: 'linear',
          display: true,
          position: 'left',
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
        {
          type: 'linear',
          display: true,
          position: 'left',
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  }
}


<Line 
   data={lineChartData.data} 
   options={lineChartData.options} 
   height={30} 
   width={80} 
   options={{ maintainAspectRatio: true }} 
/>
```